# how to get the web service response into grid view in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am new to web services.

I want to display the response of web service into a GridView in my aspx file.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first step would be to create a [client proxy and invoke the service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) and the second step would be to point the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) property of the GridView to the collection you want to bind to. The final step is to call the [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) method.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var proxy = new WebServiceClientProxy())
    {
        SomeModel[] data = proxy.GetData();
        gridView1.DataSource = data;
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```